# Unable to call any css on home page using local.xml file

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml

I have created one custom theme package.

**Package name:** custom

**Theme name:** default

Here is my `local.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">  
    <default >    
    <reference name="head">
            <remove name="" />
     <block type="core/template" name="header" template="page/html/head.phtml" />

        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/theme-animate.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/theme-blog.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/theme-global.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/theme-product.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/theme-product-list.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/theme-responsive.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/theme-rtl.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/bootstrap-theme.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/bootstrap-rtl.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/font-awesome.min.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/material-design-iconic-font.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/animate.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/nivo-slider.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/style.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/owl.carousel.css></stylesheet></action>
         <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/jslider.css></stylesheet></action>


        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/custom.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/theme.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bootstrap.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bootstrap.min.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.min.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.elevatezoom.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.magnific-popup.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.nivo.slider.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/owl.carousel.min.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/draggable-0.1.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.dependClass-0.1.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.slider.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/tmpl.js</name></action>




    </reference>

        <reference name="footer">
            <remove name="footer_links" />
            <remove name="footer_links2" />     
            <remove name="footer.newsletter" /> 
    </reference>
    </default>


</layout>
```

So can you please tell me what is the problem?

I am using Magento Version 1.9.2.4.

Comment: Is all js are included on homepage?

Comment: no not all Js are include on homepage

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your block code

**change this code from**

```
<block type="core/template" name="header" template="page/html/head.phtml" />
```

to

```
<block type="core/template" name="header" template="page/html/head.phtml" >
```

and add `</block>` before `</reference>`